# Wrapping every three elements while iterating through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a two-dimensional array (`affiliates`) where each array item consists of an image URL and a link URL. `randArray` is simply a generated list of random numbers (non-repeating) that matches the length of `affiliates`.

I've gotten to the point where I can successfully generate an HTML string for randomized image/url combinations.

(The above might be more information than needed but I wanted to provide a little background.)

What I'm trying to do is group every three iterations together and wrap in `<p>` tags. I've tried doing a nested loop inside the current one but could only get to where it was wrapping three of the *same* line in a `<p>` tag, whereas I need them to be three successive lines. I feel like this should be pretty easy, but I'm stumped. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
for(var y=0; y < randArray.length; y++) {

    var image = affiliates[randArray[y]][0];
    var url = affiliates[randArray[y]][1];

    var fullString = '<a href="' + url + '"><img src="' + image + '"></a>';
    console.log(fullString);

}
```

Comment: The solution would be something to do with modulos (%), like `(y%3 == 0)` would be the first of every three... lemme think on this.

Comment: You can either check the value of `y` to see if it's a multiple of 3, and then add the `p` tags, or you can do a nested loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WIthin your loop, `y % 3 == 0` will be true on the first iteration and every third after it, so output your `<p>` when `y % 3 == 0` and your `</p>` when `y % 3 == 2` and after your loop if `length % 3 != 0`.

But a nested loop is probably easier to do and maintain:

```
var x, image, url;
var fullString = "";
var y = 0;
while (y < randArray.length) {

    fullString += '<p>';
    for (x = 0; x < 3 && y < randArray.length; ++x, ++y) {
        image = affiliates[randArray[y]][0];
        url = affiliates[randArray[y]][1];
        fullString += '<a href="' + url + '"><img src="' + image + '"></a>';
    }
    fullString += '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var y=0; y < randArray.length; y++) {

var image = affiliates[randArray[y]][0];
var url = affiliates[randArray[y]][1];
var fullString = '';
if(y%3 == 2){
    fullString += '<p>';
} 
fullString = '<a href="' + url + '"><img src="' + image + '"></a>';
if(y%3 == 2){
    fullString += '</p>';
} 
console.log(fullString);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand, but...

```
var t = [];
for(var i=0;i<affiliates.length;i++) t.push(i);
while(t.length>2){
 var str = '';
 for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
  str += '<a href="';
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*t.length);
  str += affiliates[t[r]][1] + '"><img src="';
  str += affiliates[t[r]][0] + '"></a>';
  t.splice(r,1);
 }
 str = '<p>'+str+'</p>';
 console.log(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, but it's not optimized code, sorry :/

```
var counter = 1; //external counter for module (%3)
var open = false;
var tagOpen = '<p>';
var tagClose = '</p>';
var fullstring = '';
var buffer = ''

for(var y=0; y < randArray.length; y++) {

    var image = affiliates[randArray[y]][0];
    var url = affiliates[randArray[y]][1];    

    //groups entries 
    buffer += '<a href="' + url + '"><img src="' + image + '"></a>';

    if(counter % 3 == 0){
        fullstring = tagOpen + buffer + tagClose; //concat strings
        console.log(fullString);
        open = false; //set open to false
    } else {
        open = true;
    }

    counter++;
}

//if at the end of the loop there's still an open tag, close it
if(open){
    fullstring += tagClose;
}
```